# react native 2 flatlist horizontal and vertical both in view issue with scroll

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have 2 flatlist in my screen (maybe will more in future) one in horizontal mode and another vertical

but they not position reletive to screen, it seems position absolute

[image]

my code :

```
render() {
      return (
       <View>
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.topData}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <ItemSample item={item} />}
                    horizontal={true}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.slug}
                    refreshing={this.state.topLoading}
                    onRefresh={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}
                />
            </View>

            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.lastData}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <ItemSample item={item} />}
                    horizontal={false}
                    numColumns={2}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.slug}
                    refreshing={this.state.lastLoading}
                    onRefresh={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
                
        
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this..

```
render() {
      return (
    <ScrollView>
       <View style={{flex:1}}>
           
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.topData}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <ItemSample item={item} />}
                    horizontal={true}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.slug}
                    refreshing={this.state.topLoading}
                    onRefresh={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}
                    horizontal
                />
          

            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.lastData}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <ItemSample item={item} />}
                    horizontal={false}
                    numColumns={2}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.slug}
                    refreshing={this.state.lastLoading}
                    onRefresh={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
      <ScrollView>
                
        
      );
    }
```

Comment: it work but got error (VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation)

Comment: Yeah.. I also get that same warning... but as documented you can ignore that warning.. if you are using 2 scroll vertically and horizontally

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your View i.e. containing **FlatList** is covering the whole screen i.e.will be treated **absolute**.

If you don't want it to be absolute, you should add these Views inside **ScrollView**.

Comment: with **ScrollView** it got error (VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation)